# By reading .hex and .map, how can I be sure that a BL links to the right function offset?

Tags: assembly, arm, stm32, machine-code, instruction-set

I'm currently doing an "hex compare" for fun to understand what is happening.

*I know that comparing hex sometimes gives too much changes to be compared.*

By just changing a function call, I can make a small change happen in the hex.
My embedded code contains `Foo(5);`, which I replaced it by `Bar(5);` (the signature of which is identical), then by `Bla(5);`.

When I compare the hex files I have the following:

[image]

The part in green is the CRC.

With the help of the hex file and the map file, how can I be sure that Foo has indeed been replaced by Bar or Bla, and not by another function?

[image]

Here's what I found that in the ARMv7-M arch doc [link](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0403/eb/DDI0403E_B_armv7m_arm.pdf). But even after knowing the offset, I still don't know if I can figure something out of this...how to transcript the .map addresses in machine code?

In the .map, respective addresses are:

[image]

I'm working on a STM32L4xx (cortex M4) with IAR compiler.

Comment: Why wouldn't it have been? You should be able to check by looking at the addresses of those functions in the map file, and checking that the differences in offsets match.

Comment: It is not code or at least not linked code.  For instance the first has, `and pc, r3, r6, ror #25` which is a non-sense instruction.  Also should call this 'intel hex' and not hexdump.  You should type in the addresses.  It takes a long time to translate from your picture to get a binary to run `objdump` on the values.  Also giving **relavent** parts of the source and map file would help,

Comment: please provide the addresses from the map file for these addresses in question, Foo, Bar, Bla...

Comment: why do you think the linker didnt do its job?

Comment: ho I'm sure the linker did its job, I'm just curious about this.

Comment: addresses were added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always you need the arm architectural reference manual (as well as technical reference manual) for that core.  The cortex-m4 trm will tell you that it is an armv7-m architecture and you get the arm for that.

BL is two separate instructions even though it is often shown as if it were 32, they don't have to execute back to back but have to execute in the right order (and you cant mess with lr in between):

```
11110xxxxxxxxxxx
11111xxxxxxxxxxx
```

so

```
0xF0E6

00011100110000000000000

0xFC03

00011100110000000000000
           100000000110
00011100110100000000110
00011100110100000000110

000 1110 0110 1000 0000 0110
0x0E6806+4+PC
```

Or write a program (doesn't handle the sign extension on H=10 because you don't have those bits set):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    ra=a&0x7FF;
    ra<<=12;
    ra|=(b&0x7FF)<<1;
    ra&=0xFFFFFFFE;
    ra+=4;
    printf("PC(inst)+0x%08X\n",ra);
}
int main ( void )
{
    fun(0xF0E6,0xFC03);
    fun(0xF008,0xFD03);
    fun(0xF0C7,0xFC03);
    return(1);
}
```

gives:

```
PC(inst)+0x000E680A
PC(inst)+0x00008A0A
PC(inst)+0x000C780A
```

What is the address of the bl instruction in question?  Being an Intel hex file it cannot be determined from what you have provided.  (I prefer srec with the 32 bit address).

The older/est ARM ARM, the armv5 one is better for seeing the two instructions, but there is a typo/bug in that document the thumb version you don't strip off two lower bits that would be the arm version of that instruction.

```
.thumb
bl here
nop
bl here
nop
nop
nop
here:



00000000 <here-0x10>:
   0:   f000 f806   bl  10 <here>
   4:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   6:   f000 f803   bl  10 <here>
   a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   c:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)


PC(inst)+0x00000010
PC(inst)+0x0000000A
```

Note that with GNU assembler you can't just use the .word or .hword trick, you have to use .inst.n:

```
.thumb
bl here
nop
bl here
nop
nop
nop
here:
.inst.n 0xf000
.inst.n 0xf806

00000000 <here-0x10>:
   0:   f000 f806   bl  10 <here>
   4:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   6:   f000 f803   bl  10 <here>
   a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   c:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

00000010 <here>:
  10:   f000 f806   bl  20 <here+0x10>
```

with one of yours:

```
.thumb
.inst.n 0xF0E6
.inst.n 0xFC03

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   f0e6 fc03   bl  e680a <.text+0xe680a>
```